# shrink the x-axis with ggplot2

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

i obtained this plot using the package ggplot2

[image]

using the code:

```
ggplot(count(c4l.tweets, "by.hour"), aes(x=by.hour, y=freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + xlab("Number") + ylab("Date") + labs(title="#c4l13 tweets by the hour")
```

I would like to shrink the time axis only on the first grid.
I tried:

```
ggplot(count(subset(c4l.tweets, time > as.POSIXct("2013-02-12 09:00:00", tz="CST") & time    <   as.POSIXct("2013-04-14 12:00:00", tz="CST"), "by.hour"), aes(x=by.hour, y=freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + xlab("Number") + ylab("Date") + labs(title="#c4l13 tweets by the hour")
```

but it doesn't work, it gives me a blank graph...

And more, If i would like to make it look like a time series plot? what aestethic i should use (ie, connect each point)?

Thank you very mych, Vincenzo

Comment: Try the `xlim(low, high)` function in ggplot. By the way, it is considered polite in SO to provide a dataset so we can reproduce your problem and test any solutions. Either put an abreviated dataset into your question, or post a link to the full dataset.

Comment: i am sorry.... next nime i will not forget.... the data is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsyivMoYhk87dFljMUZURWZMYzNzT2lwcEduUUJ6d1E#gid=36 in the tab "Archive"... i tried with xlim, using a time strip, but it says thats i should not use a discrete element

Answer (score 0):

Importing the table you provided in the link as a dataframe `c41.tweets`, you can set limits as follows.

```
df      <- data.frame(time=c41.tweets$time)
df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df$hour <- as.POSIXct(cut(df$time, breaks="hour"))

freq    <- data.frame(table(df$hour, dnn="hour"))
freq$hour <- as.POSIXct(freq$hour)

start <- as.POSIXct("2013-02-01 09:00:00")
end   <- as.POSIXct("2013-03-01 12:00:00")

ggp <- ggplot(freq) 
ggp <- ggp + geom_bar(aes(x=hour,y=Freq),stat="identity")
ggp <- ggp + labs(title="c4l13 Tweets by the Hour [Feb-01 to Mar-01]")
ggp <- ggp + labs(y="Count", x="2013")
ggp <- ggp + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold"))
ggp <- ggp + xlim(start,end)
ggp
```

[image]

Regarding your second question, is this what you had in mind?

```
ggp <- ggplot(freq)
ggp <- ggp + geom_line(aes(x=hour,y=Freq))
ggp <- ggp + labs(title="c4l13 Tweets by the Hour [Feb-01 to Mar-01]")
ggp <- ggp + labs(y="Count", x="2013")
ggp <- ggp + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold"))
ggp <- ggp + xlim(start,end)
ggp
```

[image]